# Prioriy for code inside link in a directive and directives in its template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Question:**
I want to know if there's a control in angular to run code inside dir1 before dir2 as the scope is updated?

```
    .directive('dir1'), function() {
     return {
      template: '<dir2></dir2>',
      link: function postLink(scope) {

       scope.$watch(function() {
        /** I want this $watch code to run before
         *  $watch code inside dir2
         *  as dir2 depends on attributes from this element
         */
       }

      }
     }
    }
```

**Temporary solution:**
I temporary use a $timeout inside dir2's $watch function to fetch updates from dir1, but if I later want a dir3 inside dir2 then I would have to use multiple $timouts and the code gets ugly.

So is it possible to set the priority for this? I have already tried the 'priority' setting, but that didn't help.

Comment: Maybe you want to add a `controller: function () {...}` in there and use the `$scope.$watch` in there? Your `<dir2>` can also require another controller, see the docs for further clarification.

Comment: have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231294/angularjs-inject-required-directive-controller-into-the-controller-instead-of-t/21231428#21231428

Comment: @Michael Thanks! Using preLink instead of postLink is what I was looking for. If you add that as answer I will check it ;)