# AngularJS directive use required controller in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Say I have the following two directives that work with each other

```
directive('parent', function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        require: 'ngModel',
        controller: function($scope) {
            this.doSomething = function() {
                //How to use ngModelController here?
            };
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelController) {
        }
    };
});

directive('child', function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        require: '^parent',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, parent) {
            parent.doSomething();
        }
    };
});
```

How can I use the `ngModelController` from within the controller of `parent`?  I suppose I could do `scope.ngModelController = ngModelController` inside the link function but that seems hacky.  Is there a better solution?

Comment: I guess you could put it in the scope in the link function? Does seem slightly hacky, but can't think of anything else...

Comment: Try require: '?ngModel'. That should bubble up through parents looking for the controller.

Comment: Apparently this was a duplicate!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231294/angularjs-inject-required-directive-controller-into-the-controller-instead-of-t

Answer (score 0):

Is this any less hacky?

```
directive('parent', function() {
    var ngModelCtrl = null;
    return {
        scope: {},
        require: 'ngModel',
        controller: function($scope) {
            this.doSomething = function() {
                //How to use ngModelController here?
                if (ngModelCtrl) {
                }
            };
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelController) {
            ngModelCtrl = ngModelController;
        }
    };
});
```